# Best provider for webinar hosting

Tags: video, web-applications, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

We are looking at running some webinars soon, and I was wondering if you folks had any experience with a service you have been happy with.

We are currently looking at using one of the following (but are always up to suggestions):

http://www.megameeting.com/overview.html

https://www.videoseminarlive.com/index.aspx

http://www.webex.com/

We also looked at:
http://www.gotomeeting.com

But they seem to not support video at this time.

Specifically, we need to be able to provide a live video feed from an instructor (as well as display slides), and accept questions/discussions from the audience via audio or chat. Of course, it is always good to have a clean interface, and if the system works without installing any software, that is a plus as well.

Any thoughts??

--Edited to provide details for system requirements.

Comment: I've attended meetings with both webex and gotomeeting. They worked fine. What are your specific requirements though?

Comment: Good question! I've edited my original question to include our requirements. Basically, we need to be able to have a live video feed, and participate in discussions with our audience. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always the free:
http://www.justin.tv/

but by far this would be my favorite:
http://www.ustream.tv/

its free (there's a paid version too with added benefits) but u can create your own channel + save old content.

Comment: I suppose these could work if you were looking for a 1-way webinar and had your own screencasting software. But dedicated webinar platforms provide voice/text chat capabilities and take less bandwidth for higher picture quality since you're just presenting slides most of the time.